# Functional programming partial functions and global scope

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

In FP the global functions/constants are avoided.

So my question is are partial functions pure ?

If I have to calculate the area of a circle for example, i have something like this:

```
const calcArea = PI => radius => PI * radius * radius
```

So I can partially apply it:

```
const calcAreaCircle = calcArea(Math.PI) //

calcAreaCircle(5) => // 3.13 * 5 * 5 = 78.53981633974483
```

So if I change the PI and run the program again i will get different results:

```
const calcAreaCircle = calcArea(Math.PI+2)
```

So what's the point to partially apply the function since it becomes some kind of global variable, it's pure but it is not `DETERMINISTIC` it can be change and if you change it other function will change the results depending on the PI constant.

Ignore the constant - i t can be variable, config or something that can change in the real world.

For me it is like global database object - if you change it many functions will change the output as well.

Is there any way to avoid global scope and to make the function pure, but without pasing PI to every call.

If the function accepts more than 2 parameters it becomes nightmare to support it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why isn't `calcAreaCircle` deterministic? For each set of arguments you get a single, distinct result. Passing `Math.PI+2` makes no sense if you are interested in calculating the area of course. FP doesn't keep you from doing illogical things. It just keeps you from performing effects without further precautions.

Comment: Imagine PI is variable, this was just an example, imagine PI is database function or something. If I dont know that it is curried, I would expect to be deterministic (same arguments - same output). You code database function i code my module in big system. So if tomorrow you pass another database function with different results I will get different output with the same calcAreaCircle arguments - so I cannot test the function if i want to be isolated (in this case I should know about code that you wrote - which is bad). Hope it makes sense.

Comment: There are no variables in FP. If you need an altered value, create a new constant with that value. How? Pass the expression that performs the altering to another function, so that the altered value is held in the call stack as a constant. This is how FP handles variables. There are none.

Comment: And if you don't know upfront how often you have to alter a value, create a recursive function call.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant function. You create module db with some function and I use getUser(integer id) - which you give me already curried. So from my point of view db function doesnt exists-it's your module. So If i suggest getUser is deterministic I could test it but tomorrow you can give me another curried function. Tha'ts my point. I should not know about your module because i guess you are in different team or something.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is are partial functions pure?

Yes, they are pure.

`calcArea(Math.PI)` and `calcArea(Math.PI + 2)` have *independent [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)*, what you're mistakenly referring to as

> some kind of global variable

This notion is incorrect. Each partial application does not share some sort of "global closure" with others.

Consider the following example:

```js
const mult = x => y => x * y
const times5 = mult(5)

console.log('5 * 4 =', times5(4))

const times3 = mult(3)

console.log('3 * 6 =', times3(6))
console.log('5 * 6 =', times5(6))
```

Note that the definition `const times3 = mult(3)` does *not* affect the closure created by `const times5 = mult(5)`. That is what is meant by *independent*.

> other function will change the results

This is demonstrated to be *false* by the example above.

> So what's the point to partially apply the function

The answer is reusability through functional composition.

Comment: It can be pure but it's not transparent. Imagine on each request times5 you pass different value - so every call to mult(3) can be different - this is bad from fp perspective - the function is not deterministic anymore.

Comment: This is the same as OOP - we same some property when constructing and use it later in the second function - the property can be function or object - what we shall win with FP approach instead of OOP ?

Comment: @user2693928 also to specifically address the edit in your question, changing the input to the function and suggesting that the function is not deterministic because its output differs is absurd. That's equivalent to suggesting `(x, y) => x + y` is not deterministic because changing `x` causes the output to be different. Determinism is about repeatability. If you can replicate the result consistently, it's deterministic. That's it.

Comment: Yes, but I receive curried function with 1 argument. For me calling 
getUser(20) -> null
getUser(20) -> {id: 20, username:'admin'} 
for example is not deterministic

Comment: @user2693928 Your example has nothing to do with the mechanism of currying.

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion comes from the fact that you have assigned two different functions to a `const` that has the same name.

```
const calcArea = PI => radius => PI * radius * radius
const aFunction = calcArea(Math.PI)
const aDifferentFunction = calcArea(3.13)
```

The two different functions `aFunction` & `aDifferentFunction` are both pure, since they will both always return the same result given the same radius argument.

One possible advantage of defining functions like this is that you may have your values for PI and for radius available at different moment of the life of your program. So it maybe useful to store a reference to PI in the scope of a function, and then later on, once the radius value is available, just call this function without knowing anything about where does PI come from and how its value has been decided.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, my point is that it is pure but not deterministic. If PI is different on each request for example you cannot test calcArea anymore because each time it can be producing different results

Comment: It's basically OOP oriented programming, the closure is the same as class property which is used later in the second function. Whats we win if we write it with fp instead of OOP ?

Comment: If you do not own the code, you should not test for it. Either you can mock the function (e.g. in your unit tests) in order to test only what you do with the function (no matter what it does) either you use that function as-is in your tests (e.g. in your functional tests) - they will probably break if the third-party function changes, but that is usually good to know and what tests are for, spotting breaking changes or needed update